# Access System date In EditView in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, editview

I have to access Current system and display in EditView in android.I am using this code.please help me.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.your_edittext_id );

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd" ); 
editText.setText( sdf.format( new Date() ));
```

Comment: click on right symbol of my answer plz

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date date = fmt.parse(Your date);
                editText.setText( date.toString());
```

Comment: @Rohit Please do *not* ask people to vote/accept your posts. They will if they want to.

Comment: @AndrewBarber but he first comment on my answer "thanks", then why he not accepting answer ?

Comment: @Rohit It's his business whether and when he accepts or votes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display actual system date, use Calendar static instance:

```
        Calendar c;
    c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date d = c.getTime();
    String date = sdf.format(d);
```